# Creating a Box-Plot but by value_counts() [Number of events occurred]

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe. Each entry is an event that occurred [550624 events]. Suppose we are interested in a box-plot of the **number of events occurring per day each month.**

```
print(df)         
          Month  Day
0           4    1
1           4    1
2           4    1
3           4    1
4           4    1
      ...  ...
550619     10   31
550620     10   31
550621     10   31
550622     10   31
550623     10   31

[550624 rows x 2 columns]
```

```
df2 = df.groupby('Month')['Day'].value_counts().sort_index()
Month  Day
4      1      2162
       2      1564
       3      1973
       4      1620
       5      1860

10     27     2022
       28     1606
       29     1316
       30     1674
       31     1726
```

```
sns.boxplot(x = df2.index.get_level_values('Month'), y = df2)
```

[Output of sns.boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWnYk.png)

My question is whether this way is the most efficient/direct way to create this visual info or if I am taking a round-about way of achieving this.
Is there a more direct way to achieve this visual?

Comment: How about [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and [`plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) : `pd.crosstab(df['Day'], df['Month']).plot(kind='box')`

Comment: @ChrisA Thanks! This is a more direct way of getting the output. Also, if I put sns.boxplot(data=crosstabbed df), it prints out the same output.

Comment: If i were using `seaborn`, i'd [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) the crosstab first. ie `sns.boxplot(data=pd.crosstab(df['Day'], df['Month']).melt(), x='Month', y='value')`

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the help!